# Hosting the SharePoint site for first time

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

I have created a SharePoint site for internet users, and it's working beautiful for me.

But when others click on the URL they see the IIS logo and getting:

> Resource cannot be found.

What can the problem be?

Comment: can you show a image with the error?

Comment: Hi Sorry not able to at attach the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check in and publish your pages. Also you need to give the users the proper permissions to view the sites.

Check in and publish can be done by see each individual page in site contents and using the options you get to check in.

Permissions are done in the site settings. Create groups and give read permissions and add whoever you want to have access to the site.

Comment: Thanks... the problem is I need to add the url to host file of each system.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the statement. Do you mean add the Sharepoint URL to for each system trying to access the URL?